# app_offline.htm doesn't bring the site down

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an Umbraco website on my Azure app service and it is working fine. I want to bring the site down nicely to do some maintenance so I've added created an "app_offline.htm" file and when I put it on the root of my website locally (on my machine IIS 10, windows 10) it immediately shut downs the website.

But when I copy the file to the root directory of my website on app service (D:\home\site\wwwroot> using KUDU) it doesn't do anything.
What should I do?

Comment: Can't repro, maybe it's just browser cache? If you're using the local cache feature in App Service you may need to restart the site for the new file to be picked up.

Comment: You were right! I needed to restart my app service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The answer for the next person who faces this problem

Ok, I've restarted my app service and it made the app_offline work fine as evilSnobu mentioned in the comment.

Also, recycling the app should work. I've changed my webconfig (added one space somewhere ) and the app_offline started to do its job! :)